# Pandas does not show the complete csv file

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

I am trying to print the entirety of an excel sheet which is 900 rows and 6 columns big. I am trying to use pandas to show it. The problem is that it shows the first few rows and columns, then skips to the last few rows, completely skipping the rest.

Here is my code

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Downloads\research-and-development-survey-2019-csv.csv',
                 encoding= 'unicode_escape')

print(df)
```

This is the output after executing:

[image]

How do I print the whole csv file? I
If it is a matter of being too big to be printed, what other choices do I have? I have tried the chunksize function, but I must be doing it wrong since it does not print the csv file at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):  
    print(df)
```

if you are using Jupyter notebook use `display(df)` instead of `print(df)`

Context manager is used to temporarily set options.

Here I am saying that `display.max_rows` and `display.max_columns` should be `None` (No limit) by default it is 10 and display.max_columns is 5

> DOCS: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.option_context.html

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! It now prints all rows of the file but only prints the first column. Do you know what could be causing this?

Comment: hey @rod.hoda, I have added the explanation!
I hope it helps :)

Comment: I fixed it! I changed the none value for the max_columns to the number of columns in the file and it printed all columns. Thank you for the explanation.